# Can the pattern "_." be used in head?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, argument-patterns

The standard usage of the pattern `_.` seems usually used in the parameter, for example, `f_[a_,n_.]`. I wonder if such pattern can be used to match the head of an expression. It appears syntactically legal (i.e., pass the kernel); however, I can't figure out a *meaningful* example that uses this mechanism. (Also, I failed to create an expression that matches some pattern like `f_.[a_]`, etc.) So does it make sense to use it? In what circumstance?

Comment: The docs for [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) make this look doubtful.  "The necessary values for `Default[f]` must always be defined before `_.` is used as an argument of `f`."  If `_.` appears as a head rather than as an argument, it seems like all bets are off.

Answer (score 3):

It is at least possible to make a definition if there is a Symbol to attach the rule to, e.g.:

```
a[_.["fly"]] := "swat"

b /: _.[b] := "upset"

a[foo["fly"]]

foo[b]
```

> ```
> "swat"
>
> "upset"
> ```

However it both examples it could be replaced with a plain [`Blank[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) (`_`) with the same apparent effect.  I think this makes sense, because a head is a single expression rather than a sequence of them; you cannot have e.g. `(x, y)[arg]`.  I suppose one might want to omit the head, e.g. have `a["fly"]` to evaluate and reference a [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) value for the head, but based on how I understand the standard evaluation to work I would expect that to be possible either.

Comment: I'm late returning to the party, but I have a few comments:  (1) Did you mean "but based on how I understand the standard evaluation to work I would expect that **not** to be possible either" (in the last line)?

Comment: (2) `b /: _.[b] := "upset"` gives me not one but two errors -- both `Message[Optional::optloose, _.]`.  I'm using `$Version` `"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`.  (One might say v11 is "upset" about this :p)

Comment: Actually, the `Message[Optional::optloose, _.]` seems quite descriptive -- I think I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have time to write the answer to my satisfaction, and I was confused for a while, but now I'm convinced I solved it.  I was confused that the error was triggered by `b /: _.[b] := "upset"` but not simply by `_.[b]` or `_.[b] :> "upset"`.  But it *is* triggered by `whoCares /. _.[b] :> "upset"` -- the message is triggered only when a an expression 'misusing' `_.` or `x_.` is **passed to a function that expects a pattern**.  Two such functions are `ReplaceAll` and `TagSetDelayed`.